# Does application pool version 4 support .net Framework 4.5.1?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, application-pool

I deploy a project with ASP.NET MVC with a target of `Framework 4.5.1`.

In Plesk I have this version :

[image]

and in `web.config` I have this :

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" maxRequestLength="2147483647" 
             executionTimeout="1600" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2147483647" />
<compilation targetFramework="4.5.1">
```

I getting this error :

[image]

I contact with provider and they told me our host support `.NET Framework v4.5.1`
I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: I changed compilation to `4.5` , but getting Access Denid error .

Comment: Sounds like your host does not support 4.5.1 which if really bad, because Microsoft does not support .net <4.5.2. End of life support ended nearly 6 months ago. My advice, switch hosting, because i wouldn't trust a company that is that behind in keeping their servers up to date, and ask for a refund.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 4.0.30319.17626 means .NET 4.5 RC, as you could see in the [table of versions](http://deletionpedia.org/en/List_of_.NET_Framework_versions).

.NET 4.5.1 starts with 4.0.30319.18408 however.